# Laravel get value from array of inputs Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

If my `$request->get('users')` returns:

```
Array
(
    [password] => 14032001
    [password_confirmation] => 14032001
)
```

how can I access the `password` field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `$request->get('users')['password']` work?

Comment: Dumb me, thanks seems logic. But how can I replace a value?

`$request->replace(array('password', sha1($request->get('users')['password'])));`

Comment: I never did this manually, but maybe you want something like this: `$request->replace(['password' => Hash::make($request->get('users')['password'])]);`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$data = new \App\Model($request->all());
```

And then access the fields like:

```
$data['password']
```